# A social network called "socialnetwork" in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, referrer, social-media

I have stumbled across a social network that Google analytics recognises as simple "socialnetwork" which is referring some users to my site, as shown in the image below:

[image: User acquisition example]

Does anyone know where this traffic is coming from?

Comment: Go on Acquisition -> All traffic -> Channels. Search for it clicking more in depth. Where do you find it?

Comment: @lucgenti Interestingly enough it displays as "socialnetwork / facebook", but Facebook traffic usually shows as m.facebook.com etc. Perhaps Google have changed their categorisation?

Comment: Click on it, then add `Full referrer` as secondary dimension. What's the URL? That's where it comes from. I've never seen facebook as referral without the `.com`. Maybe it's some URL campaign parameter that needs to be changed.